# Is there a way to detect if there is any open drawer?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dialog, flutter-drawer

I have a Flutter app that displays an animation. I want the animation to pause if there is an open Drawer or a modal dialog (like `showModalBottomSheet`) displayed anywhere in the App.

I could handle the events of a specific Drawer directly and manage the state on my own. However, I have multiple drawers in my app that I have to track and it feels like a lot of work. Is there a global place were I can check whether a Drawer (or modal dialog) is open anywhere in the app?

Comment: Why was my answer deleted?

Comment: @sagaracharya Not sure, but it was still helpful, thanks!

Comment: It was helpful to you that's great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both `showModalBottomSheet` and modal dialogs are pusing a route to the `Navigator`. This way one can check via `ModalRoute.of(context)?.isCurrent != true` whether another route (or dialog) is in front of the current route.

Sadly, the open `Drawer` of a `Scaffold` is not a route. However it isn't required to have a key on the scaffold, but one can check via `Scaffold.of(context).isDrawerOpen` if the next parent `Drawer` is open.

By combining the two state I can check whether the animation should be paused.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is way to know whether navigation drawer is opened or not

**1. Declare GlobalKey**

```
  GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
```

**2. Assign a key to Scaffold Widget**

```
 return Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
```

**3. Used wherever you want to know drawer status**

```
_scaffoldKey.currentState.isDrawerOpen   // This return bool value True-Open, False-Close
```

Comment: This is what I have right now, but I have multiple Scaffolds, modal dialogs and I'm also using `showModalBottomSheet`. I'm s struggling a bit with handling the state of all of them on my own.

Comment: Then you must create common Scaffold Base class and implement this functionality there

Comment: This doesn't answer the question properly, neither you show you he would implement that in case of many drawers nor you added the dialog part.